# How to get OpenGL Shader Language 1.4 working with Intel HD Graphics 4000? (Trusty/14.04)

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl, mesa

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (`trusty`) on an Ultrabook with the i7-3537U CPU.

This processor has the Intel HD 4000 GPU ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors#Ivy_Bridge_microarchitecture_.283rd_generation.29_2)), which supports OpenGL 3.3 under Linux ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Seventh_generation)). OpenGL 3.3 includes support for [GLSL v3.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language#Versions).

**Does anyone know how to get OpenGL 3.3 support working correctly with HD Graphics 4000 under Ubuntu 14.04?**

## Problem

I've installed Mesa 10.1.3 installed from the standard repos (the [Mesa 10.1.3 release notes](http://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/10.1.3.html) say that OpenGL 3.3 is supported):

```
$ dpkg -l|grep mesa
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                          10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4                                   amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64                  10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4                                   amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- hardware drivers
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                       10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4                                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                       10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4                                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                         10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4                                   amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libgles2-mesa:amd64                         10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4
```

So, I'm somewhat puzzled to see that `glxinfo` reports compatibility only with **OpenGL 3.0** and **GLSL v1.30**.

```bash
$ glxinfo |grep version
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

## Goal

I am trying to run the [GpuTest benchmarks](http://www.geeks3d.com/20121113/gputest-0-2-0-cross-platform-opengl-benchmark-furmark-lands-on-linux-and-os-x/), which mostly require OpenGL 3.2. When I try to run the benchmarks, I get errors like this:

```
GLSL 1.40 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
```

Comment: Can you try using the [xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)? If I recall correctly, support for OpenGL 3.2 landed sometime around Mesa 10.4.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I added the PPA and `dist-upgrade`d all my Mesa packages... `glxinfo` still shows me `OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.1`.

Although the "core profile" is described as version 3.3... Hmmm. Is there some specific missing feature of the Intel driver?

Answer (score 1):

The [Intel Linux graphics stack](https://01.org/linuxgraphics) currently only supports up to 3.3 core profile